# Property null when it looks like it shouldn't

Tags: java, inheritance, nullpointerexception, null

I have a class **TrueFalse** that extends a class **Question**.

**Question** has a property *answers* which is an ArrayList of type **Answer**

```
protected ArrayList<Answer> answers = new ArrayList<Answer>();
```

**TrueFalse** has a method called take(Question q) which attempts to add an **Answer** to the *answers* ArrayList.

This is my problem - the *answers* ArrayList is throwing a NullPointerException and appearing as null.

```
public void take(Question question) {
    input = new Input();
    answer = new Answer();

    System.out.print("Enter Option: ");
    int response = input.getIntInput(question.options.size());
    answer.setAnswerNumber(response);

    System.out.println(question.answers); // PRINTS NULL
    question.answers.add(answer);
}
```

Does anyone have an idea why? Thanks for the help!

EDIT:

I believe this is the stack trace? I'm rather new so I think this is what we're looking for:

```
null
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Question.TrueFalse.take(TrueFalse.java:53)
at Survey.Survey.take(Survey.java:239)
at Survey.Main.mainMenuSelection(Main.java:74)
at Survey.Survey.mainMenu(Survey.java:320)
at Survey.Main.mainMenuSelection(Main.java:41)
at Survey.Survey.mainMenu(Survey.java:320)
at Survey.Main.main(Main.java:196)
```

EDIT2:

This is where the take method is being called, from my **Survey** class.

```
public void take(Survey survey) {

    if (survey.name == null && survey.questions.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("MESSAGE: Please create/load first.");
        mainMenu();
    } 

    System.out.print("Name: ");
    System.out.println(survey.name);

    for (int i = 0; i < survey.questions.size(); i++) {
        System.out.print("\n" + (i+1) + ". " + survey.questions.get(i).questionType + ") ");
        System.out.println(survey.questions.get(i).prompt);

        for(int j = 0; j < survey.questions.get(i).options.size(); j++) {
            System.out.print(j+1 + ". ");
            System.out.println(survey.questions.get(i).options.get(j));
        }

        survey.questions.get(i).take(survey.questions.get(i)); // CALLED HERE

    }
    System.out.println("Survey complete!");
}
```

EDIT3:

Here is my **Question** class

```
public abstract class Question implements Serializable {

protected static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected Input input;
protected Answer answer;
protected int optionCount = 0;

public String prompt;
public String questionType;
public ArrayList<String> options;
public ArrayList<String> correctOptions;
public ArrayList<String> matchingOptions;
public ArrayList<Answer> answers;

public Question() {
    options = new ArrayList<String>();
    correctOptions = new ArrayList<String>();
    matchingOptions = new ArrayList<String>();
    answers = new ArrayList<Answer>();
}
```

Note: I'm not the best programmer, rather new, so Its likely very sloppy :(

EDIT4:

My **TrueFalse** class:

```
public class TrueFalse extends Question implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public TrueFalse() {
    questionType = "True/False";
}

@Override
public void addPrompt() {
    input = new Input();

    System.out.println("Enter the prompt for your True/False question: ");  
    prompt = input.getStringInput();
}

@Override
public void addOption() {
    options.add("True");
    options.add("False");
}

@Override
public void addCorrectOption() {
    System.out.println("Select correct option: T/F");
    String response = input.getStringInput();

    while ((!response.toLowerCase().equals("t")) && (!response.toLowerCase().equals("f")))  {
        System.out.println("MESSAGE: Enter a valid input.");
    }
    if (response.toLowerCase().equals("t")) {
        correctOptions.add("True");
    } else {
        correctOptions.add("False");
    }
}

public void take(Question question) {
    input = new Input();
    answer = new Answer();

    System.out.print("Enter Option: ");
    int response = input.getIntInput(question.options.size());
    answer.setAnswerNumber(response);

    System.out.println(question.answers);
    question.answers.add(answer);
}
```

}

Comment: Please append complete code and stacktrace

Comment: What does the stacktrace tell you?

Comment: There's not enough information for more than a SWAG, but here's mine: Could you be shadowing the answers field by re-declaring it in the constructor? If you do this, then you initialize the local variable and not the field. Please improve your question so that we don't have to make SWAGs. As a side recommendation: don't directly access an object's fields. Instead use the `setXXX(...)`, `getXXX()`, and `addXXX(...)` public methods.

Comment: Thanks Hovercraft, I realized that I shouldn't do this about halfway into this project haha so it would take me quite a while to reverse all the damage. I don't have any redeclaration anywhere I can find.

Comment: PLease post the Question class

Comment: So what line is throwing the exception? And what values are shown as `null`? You talk about `answers` throwing an exception but it isn't even used in the method that throws the exception.

Comment: My apologies, I pasted my Question class. @Jeroen, the line `question.answers.add(answer);` throws the exception.

Comment: Question is **abstract** -- are you doing anything to answers in your concrete classes that extend Question? Are you re-declaring the variable?

Comment: Can you please post TrueFalse class?

Comment: And the Survey class? Also, why are so many classes extending Question?

Comment: I'm not redeclaring anywhere I can see, I will post TrueFalse. Thanks for sticking with me guys.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Because there are many different Question types (TrueFalse, MC, Ranking, Matching, etc)

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that you properly initialized your questions object inside your survey?

```
 survey.questions.get(i).take(survey.questions.get(i));
```

generally i'm not quit sure what is the meaning of this line. for my survey, select from my questions a particular one, then make this question activate a method on.. itself? that is why **this** keyword is intended for the first place... maybe you should try:

```
public void take() {
input = new Input();
answer = new Answer();

System.out.print("Enter Option: ");
int response = input.getIntInput(this.options.size());
answer.setAnswerNumber(response);

System.out.println(this.answers); // NO NEED TO SEND THE QUESTION TO ITSELF
this.answers.add(answer);
```

}

Comment: Yeah I'm rather new so I forget the best ways of implementing things, I tried changing to the method above and I still get the same exception on the same line. Thanks for the response!

Comment: sure thing :) can you please share how you initialized the questions in your Survey class?

Comment: I think I solved this issue, but I'm not sure why it works. Can you look at my self posted answer? Thanks!

Comment: that simply states that you haven't initialized your answers list inside your Question class (in the c'tor for instance)... be careful - if you will use the take method more then once per question object you will reset the current state of your question

Answer (score -1):

well, can't see any obvious issues here.

However, I would say the "protected" attribute using here not looking good to me, would recommend in Question class you have:

```
private ArrayList<Answer> answers = new ArrayList<Answer>();
protected ArrayList<Answer> getAnswers(){
    return answers;
}
```

In sub class TrueFalse, refer that by getter method

```
System.out.println(question.getAnswers()); 
question.getAnswers().add(answer);
```

Comment: Not your down-voter, but shouldn't a getter method be public?

Comment: Changed to use this, however still getting null. Thanks for feedback.

Answer (score -2):

I took out the assignment of the answers ArrayList in my **Question** class and put it in my take() method, as such:

```
public void take(Question question) {
    input = new Input();
    answer = new Answer();
    answers = new ArrayList<Answer>();

    System.out.print("Enter Option: ");
    int response = input.getIntInput(question.options.size());
    answer.setAnswerNumber(response);

    System.out.println(question.answers);
    question.answers.add(answer);
}
```

In **Question**, it now looks like:

```
public ArrayList<Answer> answers;
```

Does anyone have an idea why this solved it?